# getting two classes to interact

Tags: python, class, call, return, interaction

I am having trouble getting two classes to interact. Here is the code for the first class where i am importing file youtest.py:

```
from youtest import MyTest   

class RunIt(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.__class__ = MyTest

r = RunIt()
r.iffit()
```

I am trying to run class MyTest through this class (code below):

```
from sys import exit

class MyTest(object):

  def death(self):
    exit

  def iffit(self):

    oh_no = raw_input(">")

  print "What is your name?"

  if oh_no == "john":
    print "welcome john"

  else:
    print "game over"
    return 'death'
```

when i run this i get the following:

File "youtest.py", line 19
    return 'death'
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Hope this question is clear enough thanks for the help.

Comment: After I have looked at all your questions here at SO, I'd strongly suggest reading [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, this isn't how to subclass.

```
from youtest import MyTest   

class RunIt(MyTest): pass

r = RunIt()
r.iffit()
```

Although in this example `r = MyTest()` would work fine.

Your `SyntaxError` is triggered by your misuse of white space. Use four spaces for each indentation level, as is standard in Python, so you can clearly see the organization of things.

You have another problem: `return 'death'` will not call `death`, you need to `return death()` if that's what you want.

Finally, `death()` will not do anything with `exit`, just reference it. You need to do `exit()`.

Answer (score 2):

The lines starting from `print "What is your name?"` are not indented properly. In python the whitespace is significant.